# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression error?

Tags: powershell

```
# Sheet 1    
$file1 = "S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG Scorecard.xlsx" # source's full path fullpath
    $file2 = "S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\Old Models\Test1.xlsx" # destination's fullpath
    
    $x1 = new-object -c excel.application
    $x1.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
    $wb2 = $x1.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
    $wb1 = $x1.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
    $sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item(1) # first sheet in destination workbook
    $sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('ESG Risk') # source sheet to copy
    
    $sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook
    $sh1_wb1.Delete()
    
    $wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
    $wb1.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
    $x1.quit()
# Sheet 2
    
    $x1 = new-object -c excel.application
    $x1.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
    $wb2 = $x1.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source, readonly
    $wb1 = $x1.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
    $sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item(2) # Second sheet in destination workbook
    $sheetToCopy = $wb2.sheets.item('ESG Scorecard') # source sheet to copy
    
    $sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workbook
    $sh1_wb1.Delete()
    
    $wb2.close($false) # close source workbook w/o saving
    $wb1.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
    $x1.quit()
```

### ERROR BELOW

PS S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell> s:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG_Test3.ps1
Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
At S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG_Test3.ps1:26 char:1

- $sh1_wb1 = $wb1.sheets.item(2) # Second sheet in destination workbook
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

Unable to get the Copy property of the Worksheet class
At S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG_Test3.ps1:29 char:1

- $sheetToCopy.copy($sh1_wb1)  # copy source sheet to destination workb ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A01A8
At S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG_Test3.ps1:30 char:1

- $sh1_wb1.Delete()
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  ```

Comment: Which line/statement is throwing the error?

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At S:\Technology\Scripts\Red\Powershell\Research\ESG_Test2.ps1:19 char:9   
+         $wb2 = $x1.workbooks.open($file1, $null, $true) # open source ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException   
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Please add this error message into your question body.

Comment: As a side note, if you want to make your life easier when working with Excel files on PowerShell, consider installing the [ImportExcel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel).

Comment: @RedOudjehane Looks like a typo - `$x1` (letter X followed by number 1) instead of `$xl` (letter X followed by letter L)

Comment: As aside, define the Excel.Application object only once above the loop and `$xl.Quit()` after the loop. Also search for how to do `ReleaseComObject()` on the used objects so you won't run out of memory.

Comment: I've made some adjustments to the above code as well as included the error. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @RedOudjehane I haven't used Excel in a while, but perhaps the `Item()` property takes a numerical _index_ (which is likely 0-based)? So `2` actually refers to sheet number 3. Give `$wb1.sheets.item(1)` a try instead

Comment: are you sure `Test1.xlsx` has two sheets? first you copy a sheet from `ESG Scorecard.xlsx` after sheet1, then you delete sheet1, then close and save, then try and copy after sheet2, but your error is saying `$wb1.sheets.item(2)` is a bad index so I'd guess it only has one sheet.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen in most cases the excel container objects are 1-based by default, and I also checked `$wb.sheets.item(0)` specifically which does give the same `DISP_E_BADINDEX` error message where `$wb.sheets.item(1)` does not.